# Focusing moved element ends up with half-focused element

Tags: javascript, android, css, cordova, webkit

I'm developing an application with cordova/phonegap. On my login page, the form is near the bottom of the screen. When the user focuses an element, I'm moving the form to the top of the screen as otherwise it ends up underneath the keyboard.

Here's where my issue starts.

When using the compiled APK on my Galaxy Nexus (4.2.2) or visiting the page directly with the 'Browser' application, it exhibits a totally wacky behaviour.

After tapping the form element, the form moves up, the keyboard pops up... And the form element ends up in some weird half-focused state. I'm usually able to type into it, but no cursor or selection outline displays, and hitting backspace does not remove characters. Other times I can type and type into... somewhere, but nothing displays in the input box.

This same page works fine in Safari on iOS 7 and in Chrome on desktop. The page works fine in Chrome on Android.

Markup:

```
<div class="form">
    <input type="text" placeholder="focus me">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.form {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 15%;
    left: 15%;
    width: 70%;
}

input {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Javascript (with jQuery 2.0.3):

```
$(".form input").focus(function() {
    $(".form").css({'bottom':'', 'top':'15%'});
});

$(".form input").blur(function() {
    $(".form").css({'bottom':'15%', 'top':''});
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BPqGJ/

Does anyone have any idea what might be causing this? Is this a known bug in older Webkit builds? Can anyone suggest any sensible workarounds? I've been banging my head against this for way too long.

Thank you.

Comment: Did some more testing. Works in a Samsung S4's (4.2.2) "Internet" but did not work in PhoneGap. Worked on an LG Optimus G (Android 4.0.4) in both Browser and as a PhoneGap app.

Comment: Same effect if I add a negative margin on focus instead of positioning it absolutely.

Answer (score 0):

Tried calling focus() on the element after repositioning, tried doing it after a timeout (100-300 ms worked inconsistently). Tried about 50 other things.

I ended up 'fixing' it (I use the term very loosely) by performing the positioning after a 1ms timeout. My Javascript ended up:

```
$(".form input").focus(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $(".form").css({'bottom':'', 'top':'15%'});
    }, 1);
});

$(".form input").blur(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $(".form").css({'bottom':'15%', 'top':''});
    }, 1);
});
```

All strange behaviour went away. I should include the caveat that although I have theories I have no real idea at all why this works. If someone knows of a relevant bug against Webkit or some real explanation for this issue, I'm certainly still interested in hearing about it.

YMMV HTH HAND.